# i dont know the name of the table is located in sql server 2008 and i want to retrive some information regarding sales report

Tags: sql

```
Expected output like this can you help me out
```

SN  Product Description MonthToDay  This Day Last Week  Today
1   Park Admission
2   Child Free Park

```
    Total Footfall for Amusement Park
```

----in park admission
i have two rows
1 pkadmin
8 childpark -----they both come under park admission

and also the amount
1 150
2 85
wee have to add both and show in today sales like that also we have to add monthtoday,thisweeklastday means 
example
25/05/14 today revenu,  thisweektoday  18/05/14,revenue,  monthtoday 25/04/2014 revenue
i have to generate footfall for the sales report and total sales on today week month like that

can you please help me out from this

Comment: Please post an [mcve] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with sample data and code to show how far you have got and help explain where you are stuck.

Comment: you know the column names ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a structure of database in your IT team. They will help find a nessecary table)))